# How to structure database with localization?

Tags: python, flask, database-design, internationalization

I am building and international website using *Flask* framework that can handle two languages (for now): English and French, using *Flask-Babel* and I have data stored in SQL database using *SQLAlchemy* as a toolkit.

Currently, my models have several duplicated attributes for each language:

```
from project import db

class Model(db.Model)

    [...]
    name_en = db.Column(db.String)
    name_fr = db.Column(db.String)
    description_en = db.Column(db.String)
    description_fr = db.Column(db.String)
```

And in my .html template I am displaying the value using things like:

```
{% if g.locale == 'fr' %}
  {{ model.name_fr }}
{% else %}
  {{ model.name_en }}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a better way managing this? If I want to add a new language it will be tedious to modify all the templates.
Ideally I would like to put in my template something like:

```
{{ model.name[g.locale] }}
```

Is it achievable?

Comment: you should take a look at flask-babel, but your question is kinda off-topic here, or maybe too broad

Comment: I tried searching for general guidance on *how to structure an SQL database for internationalization* which is really my question but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Jay answered to create my models like this:

```
from flask import g
from project import db


class Model(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'models'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    languages = db.relationship('ModelLanguage', backref='model', lazy='dynamic')
    [...]

    def __init__(self, url):
        [...]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Model {}>'.format(self.local_name)

    @property
    def local_name(self):
        if hasattr(g, 'locale'):
            if self.languages.filter_by(locale=g.locale).first() is not None:
                return self.languages.filter_by(locale=g.locale).first().name
        else:
            return self.languages.first().name

    @property
    def local_description(self):
        if hasattr(g, 'locale'):
            if self.languages.filter_by(locale=g.locale).first() is not None:
                return self.languages.filter_by(locale=g.locale).first().description
        else:
            return self.languages.first().description


class ModelLanguage(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'models_languages'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    model_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('models.id'))
    locale = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, model_id, locale, name, description):
        self.model_id = model_id
        self.locale = locale
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Language element for model {0} in {1} >'.format(self.model_id, self.locale)
```

Therefore in my template, I can directly call `{{ model.local_name }}` to display the element in the correct language.

Comment: Oh, certainly push this into a function, yes. I didn't mean to imply to re-write the DB access every time.

Comment: Of course, it was to give a more concrete example for some newbies like me to gain time. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Flask-Babel, but the way I handle it is this:

I move all language-dependent data into a separate table with a language attribute. For example, if my one-language solution would be to have one table with, say:

```
product (product_id, name, description, price)
```

For multiple languages I create two tables:

```
product (product_id, price)
product_language (product_id, language, name, description)
```

Then when I want to retrieve the data for a particular language

```
select pl.name, pl.description, p.price
from product p
join product_language pl on pl.product_id=p.product_id
where p.product_id=@id and pl.language=@language
```

Now it's easy to add new languages. There is zero code change: just add new records to the product_language table.

You have to consider what happens if there is no record for a particular language. If you simply do an inner join like my example, then you'll get a not found, which may or may not be acceptable. In some cases this may be an error. In other cases you may want to fall back to a default language. For example, I was just working on a program where we have a table of messages in various languages. I recently added code to say that if we don't have a message with a specified name-country, fall back to the language code with no country. Like if we don't have "fr-ca", try "fr". And if we don't have that, fall back to English. (Because everybody in the world speaks English, right? But seriously, because we're an American company and I know we always have English.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know flask-babel, but as long as you stick to using the same locale names for the extension on the columns as defined in `g.locale`, then you could do this

```
{{ getattr(model, 'name_{}'.format(g.locale)) }}
```

and

```
{{ getattr(model, 'description_{}'.format(g.locale)) }}
```

Obviously, you could use other ways to build the variable name of the column you want, but `getattr` should allow you to dynamically get the value you want.

Alternatively, and this might be a nicer solution is to change what you are returning to the page.  Instead of returning the SQLAlchemy object and having code in your templates, maybe get your view handler to do the conversion beforehand and simple always return the correct language specific values in an object.  Again I don't know Flask so this might not be possible, but I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works using `{{ model['name_{}'.format(g.locale)] }}`.
(`getattr` is not accessible within the .html template, due to it being processed by *Jinja2* and not real python).

Comment: I will let the question open to see if I get more answer about good strategies for organizing the database with internationalization.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I'm surprised that you can access getattr in Jinja, as you can in both Mako and Chameleon, but TIL something about Jinja.  Thanks ;)